# User defined function and labels of a pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to define a function to plot a pie chart whenever called. This's what I'd tried:

```
def pie_plot(obj_1, obj_2, lab_1, lab_2):
"""
Args:
    obj_1: First object.
    obj_2: Second object.
    lab_1: First label.
    lab_2: Second label.
Returns:
    pie chart.
"""
x1 = obj_1
x2 = obj_2
l1 = str(lab_1)
l2 = str(lab_2)
ar_1 = np.array([x1, x2])
labels_1 = ['l1', 'l2']
plt.pie(ar_1, labels = labels_1);
plt.legend();
```

But when calling the function, for example:

```
pie_plot(A, B, C, D)
```

The labels of the chart stay l1 and l2, they do not change to C and D.

Anyone can help?

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: `labels_1 = ['l1', 'l2']` lose the quotation marks here

Comment: @PatrykKowalski Thanks. It'd done the job.